# Problem in loading large strings in the memory

Tags: android, string, memory-management

I have problem in loading large strings in the memory. I have a WebService that returns a string. Sometimes the size of this string is huge about 4MB.

My Code:

```
... 
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);

androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
```

When the size of string is huge, the program stops unexpectedly at the end line with no exceptions.

what should I do to resolve this issue?

---

**Edit:**
error log:

```
09-12 09:20:19.790: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(3515): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.845MB for 3319472-byte allocation
09-12 09:20:19.850: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 8% free 13093K/14151K, paused 3ms+2ms
09-12 09:20:28.510: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(136): @PowerManagement: Auto-dim timeout
09-12 09:20:28.510: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(136): @PowerManagement: Screen Bright {true -> false}
09-12 09:20:38.330: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2179K, 23% free 10932K/14151K, paused 42ms
09-12 09:20:38.340: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(3515): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.484MB for 4979204-byte allocation
09-12 09:20:38.390: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 17% free 15794K/19015K, paused 2ms+3ms
09-12 09:20:59.920: DEBUG/DockManagerService(136): Display mobile dock notificaiton, level:5 status:4
09-12 09:20:59.920: DEBUG/BatteryService(136): level:99 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true dock_status:4 dock_level:5 voltage: 8 temperature: 270 technology: Li-ion AC powered:true USB powered:false icon:17302732 invalid charger:0
09-12 09:20:59.930: INFO/fdhttpd(3345): battery level:99 plugged:1
09-12 09:20:59.930: DEBUG/PowerUI(184): closing low battery warning: level=99
09-12 09:21:05.070: DEBUG/dalvikvm(223): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 33% free 21283K/31431K, paused 4ms+3ms
09-12 09:21:12.440: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3267K, 34% free 12553K/19015K, paused 31ms
09-12 09:21:12.450: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(3515): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.441MB for 7468802-byte allocation
09-12 09:21:12.560: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 25% free 19846K/26311K, paused 2ms+2ms
09-12 09:21:59.380: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4902K, 44% free 14984K/26311K, paused 37ms
09-12 09:21:59.400: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(3515): Grow heap (frag case) to 25.376MB for 11203198-byte allocation
09-12 09:21:59.490: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 31% free 25925K/37255K, paused 26ms
09-12 09:21:59.540: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_CONCURRENT freed 7293K, 50% free 18631K/37255K, paused 2ms+3ms
09-12 09:22:39.230: ERROR/MPL-accel(136): ../../accel.c|AccelGetData|144 returning 146
09-12 09:22:39.230: ERROR/MPL-fifo(136): ../../mlFIFO.c|readAndProcessFIFO|569 returning 146
09-12 09:22:39.230: ERROR/MPL-ml(136): ../../ml.c|MLUpdateData|763 returning 146
09-12 09:22:39.230: ERROR/Sensors(136): MLUpdateData error (code 146)
09-12 09:23:00.230: DEBUG/BatteryService(136): level:99 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true dock_status:4 dock_level:4 voltage: 8 temperature: 269 technology: Li-ion AC powered:true USB powered:false icon:17302732 invalid charger:0
09-12 09:23:00.240: DEBUG/DockManagerService(136): Display mobile dock notificaiton, level:4 status:4
09-12 09:23:00.240: INFO/fdhttpd(3345): battery level:99 plugged:1
09-12 09:23:00.240: DEBUG/PowerUI(184): closing low battery warning: level=99
09-12 09:23:05.300: DEBUG/dalvikvm(223): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 33% free 21283K/31431K, paused 8ms+3ms
09-12 09:23:08.620: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 59K, 50% free 18631K/37255K, paused 33ms
09-12 09:23:08.620: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(3515): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16804792-byte allocation
09-12 09:23:08.650: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3515): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 8K, 51% free 18622K/37255K, paused 28ms
09-12 09:23:08.650: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(3515): Out of memory on a 16804792-byte allocation.
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515): "Thread-11" prio=5 tid=10 RUNNABLE
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4085c4b0 self=0x172650
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   | sysTid=3558 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1831224
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   | schedstat=( 4096840000 1017805000 13067 ) utm=332 stm=77 core=1
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~96)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:126)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:272)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1338)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:233)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:404)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:271)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:404)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:131)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:90)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:179)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:90)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.mabna.order.ui.ActToolDataExchange.threadGetFiles(ActToolDataExchange.java:185)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.mabna.order.ui.ActToolDataExchange.access$3(ActToolDataExchange.java:145)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.mabna.order.ui.ActToolDataExchange$6.run(ActToolDataExchange.java:134)
09-12 09:23:08.650: INFO/dalvikvm(3515):   at org.mabna.order.utils.Utilities$5.run(Utilities.java:718)
09-12 09:23:08.650: WARN/dalvikvm(3515): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401c4760)
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:96)
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:126)
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:272)
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1338)
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:233)
09-12 09:23:08.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3515):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:404)
```

Comment: When your app silently fails, there will be some messages in LogCat that give you more details, probably tagged as dalvikVm and probably in the process space of your app.  See about adding some logging of your own, but most importantly add some more details about this from what the system is logging.  You can get your app's process id from Eclipse's Devices view (Window - Show View - Other... - Android - Devices), get the process id while running, create a new filter in LogCat view by this pid, and then duplicate the bug.  It could be a memory exception, http timeout, etc

Comment: Try splitting the data into chunks of 1mb & then reassemble that on android side.This may help you to resolve memory.Other things try to create the new instance objects every time for new request.

Comment: @breceivemail Where you ever able to solve this issue? I got a similar issue at the moment...

Comment: No. I am waiting for a good solution.

Comment: @bvanvelsen I did not solve the problem. I created a webservice that builds text files and download that text files.

Answer (score 0):

Not an android master, so I may be getting a few down votes for this answer.

You say you have a web service which returns a string, so essentially you're downloading 4mb of data and loading it. Your problem here may well be the speed that your android device can download/upload data at.
Have you tried running this on a real device and watching the LogCat window? It could be that the network request is causing your main thread to timeout.

To verify this, you could try manually setting a variable with an example response that you may get from the server.
`String str = "abcd...`
If that crashes your application then I'm not sure. But if that works then it may well be your network request causing a timeout.

To solve a network request timeout, what you should actually do is run the network request in a separate thread. Examples can be found on the Android Dev site.

Comment: I am running this method in a thread and I am testing it on a real device.


I think when the problem is for timeout, I must get exception not stopping unexpectedly.

In some cases that size is less than 4MB and is about 1MB, I don’t have problem at this line but I have a decryption procedure which has the following line:

new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

When the size is about 1MB, I encounter this problem again and the application stops unexpectedly. It means that the problem is about memory management.